# Android Startactivity NavigationDrawer Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I'm using the NaviagationDrawer with the Fragment. 
Now in MainActivity, I open the various fragment but one of the lines must open an Activity.

```
/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new InFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new RiFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new RieFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

In case 4, I would like to open an activity as I do?

Comment: Now you are in an ActivityFragment, and this kind of activity is a host for fragment. You can only change the activity and go in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a new activity in `case 4:`, you can simply start a new activity with an `Intent` as you normally would.

```
...
case 4:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
...
```

You would also want to change your if/else block on the bottom to avoid logging an error when you start a new activity (since your `fragment` variable would be null in this case).

Comment: ok, now I would like to enter the `Options menu` in the `action bar` and also have the `NavigationDrawer`. That is, the change in each `Fragment` I want to display a different `Options menu`.  I tried as is done normally with the Activity but it is not the right way